# Это сделал(,) нЕсмотря на то, что

Tags: запятые

Я не понимаю: если я делаю на союзе ударение, нужна ли та запятая?

`Я это сделал вчера(,) нЕсмотря на то, что лил не мини-дождь, а дождилище.`

`Я поссорился с ним(,) нЕвзирая на то, что он мне ежевику дал.`

Comment: Вот теперь и у меня такие вопросы стали возникать. Плюсую ваш вопрос поэтому.

Comment: Кстати, ударение-то должно не на Е, а на О палать. В заголовке-то.

Comment: несмотря - это вслепую, а невзирая - это вообще не произнесешь, не то, что не сделаешь. Связанность утверждений - делал в слепую, но лил дождь - тоже доставляет отсутствие смысла. Ты хоть придумывай фразы, у которых смысл будет, чтобы не гадать, что это вообще такое. С таким же успехом можно было добавить любую другую фразу: я сделал вслепую, но кот зеленый. Логика выбора подчиненной конструкции остается для меня загадкой, она вообще нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на комментарий**

1. Как ставятся знаки **по Розенталю и по грамматике?**  Нерасчлененный союз относится к придаточному, а при его расчленении местоименная часть входит в главное предложение, в то время как союзная часть (с союзом ЧТО) относится к придаточному предложению. В обоих случаях нужна **одна запятая.**
2. Но Грамота  **В НЕКОТОРЫХ СЛУЧАЯХ** предлагает ставить две запятые.  Рассмотрим одно из предложений с двумя запятыми, взятое из Нацкорпуса:

*Было тепло и солнечно, **несмотря на то, что осень явно перешла в наступление.***

На каком основании поставлены запятые? Об этом можно только **догадываться.**

(1) Может, это нерасчлененный союз, в котором поставлена дополнительная запятая перед ЧТО? *Было тепло и солнечно, **несмотря на то, что осень явно перешла в наступление.***

(2) А может, это расчлененный союз с обособлением всего придаточного? *Было тепло и солнечно, несмотря на то, **что осень явно перешла в наступление.***

3. Или что это, **какая грамматика?**  Но, скорее всего, это давняя традиция, закрепленная Грамотой на письме. Пользователи, похоже, такие проблемы не решают, а просто ставят две запятые **при любом расположении** придаточного.

Вот такое **противостояние:**  Розенталь и грамматика против Грамоты.ру и традиционного написания.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (примеры из Нацкорпуса с двумя запятыми)

*Было тепло и солнечно, **несмотря на то, что** осень явно перешла в наступление.*

***Несмотря на то, что** окна в сад были завешены, горело электричество и в комнате было очень светло,*

***Несмотря на то, что** магазин был уже заперт, он все-таки взял с меня четвертак.*

***Несмотря на то, что** Кипренский был сыном Дьяконова, по казенным бумагам отцом его считался Швальбе.*

***Несмотря на то, что** беседка была открыта со всех сторон, сизые клубы дыма висели в воздухе.*

*И такие мысли, **несмотря на то,** что я стараюсь удалить их, приходят мне...*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149152/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Нет, Sharon, вы опять "утаиваете" важную информацию и пишете: "Грамота предлагает ставить две запятые".  Это не так. Грамота: "...союз может **целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой)**, но может и расчленяться..." Приводит примеры и **без запятой** перед ЧТО: *Он, **несмотря на то что** был в упоительном чаду пива и вина...  Мы принялись бегать по закрайку самого берега, и всё выходило отлично, **несмотря на то что** кое-где лед ломался...  Зритель должен был поверить, что перед ним человек, остающийся невредимым, **несмотря на то что** сквозь него...*

Comment: Утаиваю, а что у меня не так?  Я не рассматриваю "учение" Грамоты. Грамота в НЕКОТРЫХ случаях разрешает ставить две запятые, что все и делают, но уже когда им ВЗДУМАЕТСЯ.  Объяснить две запятые сложно. Или что не так? Учение Грамоты можно прочитать в оригинале, что же я буду его пересказывать. Вы вот сами прочитали)    Версии объяснения мы вчера долго обсуждали, пока их не отправили в чат.

Comment: Вы прекрасно знаете [**её статью**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483). А пишете без вариантов:  "В обоих случаях нужна одна запятая. **Но Грамота предлагает ставить две запятые**". Это неправда, это не соответствует тексту статьи и практике письма.

Comment: Сейчас напишу в "некоторых случаях", тогда будет правда?  Меня некоторые случаи не устраивают, это очевидное нарушение грамматики. Или нет? Или они молодцы?

Comment: Она не предлагает "в некоторых случаях". Она пишет... (смотрите мой первый после чата комментарий и не искажайте формулировки неправильным пересказом). Кто молодец, уже неважно. Я за чистоту ответов.

Comment: Я не буду ничего смотреть. Укажите в моем ответе  (сейчас) неверную информацию.  Я в ПРИНЦИПЕ  против двух запятых.  Я за чистоту грамматики.

Comment: То есть вы даже не читаете комментарии? Выхватываете только слова "утаиваю", "неправда"? Я всё уже указал, предельно ясно, а вы как будто уже издеваетесь. Ситуация напоминает ваши беседы с оleedd'ом. // Будьте В ПРИНЦИПЕ против, это ваше право, но искажать информацию не нужно.

Comment: Давайте не будем сравнивать и переходить на лица. Я за правильную грамматику и оформление текстов по Розенталю и ПАС.  Это все, что я могу сказать.  Что я "исказила" в ответе (сейчас)?  Я старалась правильно подобрать текст.

Comment: Вы просто не слышите или делаете вид, что не слышите (в этом схожесть). Я разве говорил о правильности/неправильности грамматики, что одни источники правы, а другие нет? Отметил только то, что **такого Грамота не писала**, что она говорит о возможности обоих вариантов, а не одного, на основе практики письма. Это всё, что я могу сказать.

Comment: Найдите ошибку в моем ответе,  я же  старалась улучшить его.

Comment: Всё уже сказано по три раза. Если вы не видите и не понимаете... Ладно... Хотим улучшения качества ответов, но... что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Вы не можете указать ошибку, не так ли?  Нужна конкретика, а не ваша оценка ситуации.

Comment: "Так ли, так ли". Нет, не так ли. Ещё раз. Грамота **не предлагает ставить две запятые**, и "некоторых случаях" тоже. Вот её текст: "При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться, в этом случае запятая обычно ставится и перед союзом (перед словом «несмотря»), и между его частями (перед словом «что»)".

Comment: Александр, я все это читала. Откуда это берется, почему такой индивидуальный подход к разным союзам, как это можно обосновать с точки зрения грамматики? Это просто наблюдение за практикой письма, не более того.  Это не правило: логика не обозначена, изложен материал не лучшим образом, да и какой у него статус? Никакой. Почему в ПАС этого нет?  И кто будет разбираться в особом расчленении одного союза.  Поэтому и ставят две запятые как кому хочется. Вот в чем очевидный вред "учения".  Нарушили грамматику в одном случае, а на практике получили уже не в одном.  Нельзя нарушать грамматику!

Comment: У Кустовой в каждой теме расписаны расчленяемые и нерасчленяемые союзы, и у нее нет особого статуса именно для этого союза. Позиция тоже указана (свободная). В постпозиции чисто уступительное значение, в препозиции взаимообусловленное, в интерпозиции вставочное (добавочное).  В грамматике работают специалисты по синтаксису, так зачем искажать грамматическую форму некорректным написанием.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно:

*Я это сделал вчера **несмотря на тО, // что** лил не мини-дождь, / а дождИлище.*

Я поссорился с ним **невзирая на тО, //  что** он мне ежевику дАл.

Оформление по **[Розенталю, пункт 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)** (общее правило **для всех** составных союзов):

*Он не пришел, **потому что** заболел* — упор в сообщении делается на самый факт неявки, причина ее не уточняется; *Он не пришёл **потому, что** заболел* — на первый план выдвигается указание на причину неявки.

Comment: Sharon, вам не кажется, что формулировка у Розенталя не очень? "на сам**ый** факт неявки" Так, по-моему, говорили раньше, а сейчас скажут "сам". Да? А главное, дальше – "причина ее не уточняется". Что значит не уточняется, если она прямым текстом обозначена в придаточном?

Comment: Самый — да, вроде так не говорят)  А формулировка  нормальная.  У Кустовой говорится так.  Если весь союз входит в придаточное предложение,  то главное предложение может быть закончено, сообщать о причине  необязательно (она на втором плане).  Если же местоименная часть входит в главное, то на нее падает УДАРЕНИЕ, связь получается взаимообусловленной. Главное предложение уже не является самодостаточным,  нужно обязательно указать причину.

Comment: Ну вот, у Кустовой корректно. А то "не уточняется"... "Не делается акцент", "сообщается попутно", "является второстепенным" – что-то в этом роде должно было быть.

Comment: Ему хотелось, чтобы проще и понятнее было, без ударений, а по смыслу (хотел как лучше...).

Comment: Кстати, у кустовой это общий принцип для всех СПП: они делятся на расчленяемые и нерасчленяемые. Например: Дождь такой, что на улицу не выйдешь. Тоже взаимная зависимость.

Comment: @Sharon Я с вашим ответом согласен, но если союз НЕСМОТРЯ/НЕВЗИРАЯ НА ТО ЧТО расчленяется, сохраняется ли запятая ПЕРЕД союзом? В справочнике Розенталя не написано — значит, по логике ставится только внутри. А «Грамота» говорит, что сохраняется. Как на самом деле?

Answer (score 0):

> [**Всегда  обособляются**](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/721-252_obosoblenie_obstoyatelstv.html) обстоятельства уступки, выраженные
> существительными с предлогами **несмотря на, невзирая на**. Такие обороты
> можно заменить на придаточные предложения уступки с союзом хотя.
>
> Ср.: Несмотря на дождливое лето, урожай выдался отличный (Почивалин).
> – Хотя лето было дождливым, урожай выдался отличный; Невзирая на
> сильный обстрел, Федюнинский поднялся на свой наблюдательный пункт. –
> Хотя обстрел был сильным, Федюнинский поднялся на свой наблюдательный
> пункт.